# RestFul service issue

Tags: java, rest

Trying to setup a restful service component that update a database table. Tried using both Spring RestTemplate as well as apache commons restful impl and both seems to no work.

On using
Option 1: Using Spring RestTemplate :   Results in following error
**com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token**
Option 2: Using using org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod; results in following errors
Server side error:
  **org.codehaus.jackson.JsonParseException: Unexpected character ('<' (code 60)): expected a valid value (number, String, array, object, 'true', 'false' or 'null')**

Client side error:
**The server refused this request because the request entity is in a format not supported by the requested resource for the requested method ().**
  My Restful service method is annotated as "Post" and consumes "JSON". My client side controller which initiates the RestFul call, code below

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/update", consumes="application/json")
public void updateMaintReport(
        @RequestBody Map<String, String> formModelData, 
        HttpServletRequest request, 
        HttpServletResponse response) 
        throws IOException,JsonMappingException {
    logger.log(LogLevel.DEBUG, "REACHED method updateMaintReport..");
    System.out.println("Reached method updateMaintReport.....");
    boolean errorEncountered = false;
    ReportingSession repSession = null;
    HttpSession session = request.getSession(false);

    if(session==null) {
        // TODO: code for handling invalid/expired session
    } else {
        repSession = (ReportingSession)session.getAttribute(ReportingWebConstants.REPORTING_SESSION);
        if(repSession==null) {
            errorEncountered = true;
        } 
    }

    if(!errorEncountered) {

        ServiceClient serviceClient = new ServiceClient();

        String servicesUrl = this.environment.getProperty("service_url_reports_data");
        String servicesName = this.environment.getProperty("service_name_reports_update_fnol");
        String serviceUrl = VIPUrlFactory.getServiceUrl(servicesUrl+servicesName);
        logger.log(LogLevel.DEBUG, "For update : serviceUrl: "+serviceUrl);

//Option 1: Using Spring RestTemplate :             
        LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String> headers = new LinkedMultiValueMap<String,String>();
        headers.add("Accept","application/json");
        headers.add("Content-type","application/json");
        List list = new ArrayList<Map<String, String>>(); list.add(formModelData);
        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        HttpEntity<List> requestEntity = new HttpEntity<List>(list, headers);

        ResponseEntity<List> fList = restTemplate.exchange(serviceUrl,
                HttpMethod.POST, 
                 requestEntity,
                List.class);


//Option 2: using org.apache.commons.httpclient.methods.PostMethod; -- Will be commented when option 1 block is uncommented     
        serviceClient.setParams(formModelData);
        serviceClient.setServiceUrl(serviceUrl);
        serviceClient.callRestServicePost();

        logger.log(LogLevel.DEBUG, "Posting data to service - to execute the update");

    }

}
```

In the above code, option 1 and option 2 block won't be executed simultaneously.

Below is the code block which accepts the Restful call, my server side code.

```
    @RequestMapping(value = "/update", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public void updateMainRptData(@RequestBody Map<String, String> formModelData) throws ReportingIntegrationException,
        IOException, JsonMappingException {
    String updateStmt = "UPDATE CL_SCRIPTS SET DELETE_IND = #{delete_ind},  SCRIPT_DESC = #{script_desc}, SCRIPT_TXT = #{script_txt}WHERE   COMPANY_CD = #{company_cd} AND SCRIPT_NAME = #{script_name}AND PROMPT_ID = #{prompt_id}";
    ParameterObjectDTO paramObjDTO = new ParameterObjectDTO();

    logger.log(LogLevel.DEBUG,"In Services Web: updateMainRptData()");

    if(!formModelData.isEmpty()) {
        Set<String> keySet = formModelData.keySet();
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (String key : keySet) {
            sb.append(key).append(" -- ").append(formModelData.get(key)).append("\n");
        }
        logger.log(LogLevel.DEBUG, sb.toString());
    }

    paramObjDTO.setModalForQuery(formModelData);
    paramObjDTO.setUpdateSqlStmt(updateStmt);
    maintReportingSvc.updateMaintReport(paramObjDTO);

}
```

Error Messages I see in browsers is not helpful but my JSON data is valid I believe.   Any help is appreciated. Thanks.
[image]

Comment: In option 1, where do you send formModelData? It seems to me you send an empty list, but the server expects a map.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. I have modified my question to include formModelData. I redeployed my code but still I continue to see a HTTP 404 error for option 1 which is caused due to the error _com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonMappingException: Can not deserialize instance of java.util.LinkedHashMap out of START_ARRAY token_

Comment: In option 1, pass for model data directly as so

Comment: In option 1, pass for model data directly as so: 'new http entity<map>(formmodeldata, headers)'. I am struggling with my smartphone.

Comment: @amadeus: I made the change you suggested but still the error persists. Error:  _org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest:910 | Could not complete request  
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 404 Not Found_

Comment: @amadeus: my Json request string will look like _{"company_cd":"02","script_name":"CauseOfLoss","prompt_id":"1","delete_ind":"N","script_desc":"IV Script","script_txt":"blah blah <b>blah<b>","oper":"edit","id":"1"}_  This JSON is generated by jqGrid and it has additional values "oper" and "id" which is NOT  expected by my server component. Does those extra values cause the failure of this RESTFUL call?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later I changed the signature of the method updateMainRptData and added a returntype and @ResponseBody to resolve this issue.